# In android change default alert message, while trying to take screenshot even after blocking the user

Tags: android, screenshot

Need small help, can we able to change the system default alert message.
My use case is, I restricted the user from taking the screenshots, So android OS throws an alert like "**This app doesn't allow to taking screenshot**". My question is, can we able to change this message.

Comment: AFAIK you can't but you shouldn't need to anyway. If this is an Android OS message, it already support localization. Just change the device language's and it will show appropriately for that langauge.

Comment: @DanBaruch, I need to change that default text with my own text.

Comment: Then as said, I don't think that's possible, unless you can root the device and rebuild the Android OS